# Android activity transitions

Tags: android, animation

I am currently using this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_slide_in, R.anim.right_slide_out);
```

R.anim.right_slide_in.xml is using:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="300"
    />
```

R.anim.right_slide_out.xml is using:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="300"
    />
```

This works just fine. When I go to an activity the new one appears from the right as the old one disappears to the left.

Now I want to create the *reverse* of this. Where if I go back to an activity the new one appears from the LEFT as the old one disappears to the RIGHT.

I am using: `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_slide_in, R.anim.left_slide_out);`

R.anim.left_slide_in uses:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="300"
    />
```

R.anim.left_slide_out uses:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="300"
    />
```

The activity is disappearing to the right correctly (so I *think* that left_slide_out is okay?) but the new activity isn't coming in from the left correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your animation when you go to another activity using this

```
   Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NexytActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_in_right, R.anim.activity_slide_out_left);
```

on NextActivity write this code...

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_slide_in_left, R.anim.activity_slide_out_right);

    }
```

Animation files
/ 1 / activity_slide_in_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

/ 2 / activity_slide_out_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />

</set>
```

/ 3 / activity_slide_in_left

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

/ 4 / activity_slide_out_right

```
     <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="300"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%" />

</set>
```

Comment: I would need to do more than just reverse the arguments wouldn't I? Because the right_slide_in/out transitions are both moving from left to right. Whereas I want the reverse to go right-to-left

Comment: onBackPress() method you have to write in next activity. and you can use any Animation for it

Comment: Yes I understand this. I think you have misunderstood my question though. Everything works fine except the activity I'm returning to is not entering in from the left of screen.

Comment: so you want to go next Activity using animation from RIGHT to Left ??

Answer (score 0):

you have these four options to set animation in:

[image: possible states of trasition]

and you can set these in your style file like below:

```
<resources>

<style name="XYZAppTheme" parent="XYZAppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/custom_transition1</item>
    <item name="android:windowReenterTransition">@transition/custom_transition2</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/custom_transition3</item>
    <item name="android:windowReturnTransition">@transition/custom_transition4</item>
</style>
```

assuming you have defined the custom transitions in your transition folder.